# Background image not properly shown Safari

Tags: css, safari

I have an issue with Safari browser, as it shown white background and not shown proper background image, whereas it works fine in other browsers. Please check the link http://testurproject.tk/deveod/EOD-New/user_pricing.html and the CSS is:

```
.site-footer {
clear: both;
background-image: url(../images/footer-bg.jpg);
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover;
-ms-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
position: relative;
padding: 90px 0px 10px;
margin: 0px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
min-width: 1080px;
background-color: transparent;

}
```

Comment: check the size of your image - I know that in the past I have had a problem if the image was too large

Comment: but it is background image, even it is well shown in body header.

Comment: Yes safari has a problem if the image is too large and will not render it